# Bpel Deployment failed within the engine, Cannot find definition for service

Tags: web-services, composition, bpel

I have problem when creating a BPEL Project that invoke external web-service

it seems that the server can't see the description of service

> 12:13:34,384 ERROR [NStateLatch] Latch error, was releasing for state 1 but actually in -1
>   12:13:34,387 WARN  [ProcessStoreImpl] Deployment failed within the engine, store >undeploying process.
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: Cannot find definition for service {[http://www.example.org/AvailableFlightTest/]}FlightService in the context of process {[http://testthree]}TestThree-48

I check the port and the name of service and all thing is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your wsdl end point url is not working. Open wsdl, find endpoint url (under tag soap: address location), which is being called during your deployment.

try to open this end point url in web browser, you will get exact error or issue which might be causing this problem.

Regards,
ambuj
"Master yourself, Master the enemy"

Comment: Thank you ,yes I found it like this http://localhost:8081/FlightServiceTest/services/FlightServiceSOAP

but how to correct it ??

Comment: open cmd, type ipconfig -all, copy your ipv4 address and replace localhost with this ip address in your WSDL, now save your wsdl and use it in your deployment once again. It should be resolved.